# Проблема с изменением свойства RichEdit.Color через наследника TPanel

Tags: delphi

Почему-то при добавлении созданного компонента на форму выбивает эту ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но такая проблема только тогда, когда я пытаюсь присвоить FCaption.Colors:= `цвет`;
Без этого присваивания всё отлично добавляется. Пробовал изменить через процедуру (SetColor), но Delphi просто закрывается, без каких либо ошибок. Дело совсем не в `Parent`, по крайней мере, я так думаю.

```
unit LabeledPanel;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Types,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  LabeledPanelTools;

type
  TLabeledPanel = class;
  //TLabeledPanelChange = procedure (Sender: TLabeledPanel; Title: String) of object;

  TLabeledPanelCaption = class(TRichEdit)

end;


  TLabeledPanel = class(TPanel)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    FCaption: TLabeledPanelCaption;
    //FOnChange: TLabeledPanelChange;
    FTitle: String;
    FShowCaption: Boolean;
    FColor: TColor;
    procedure SetCaption(const Value: String);
    procedure SetShowCaption(const Value: boolean);
    procedure SetColor(const Value: TColor);
  public

  protected
  published
    property Caption: String read FTitle write SetCaption;
    property ShowCaption: boolean read FShowCaption write SetShowCaption;
    property Color: TColor read FColor write SetColor;

  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents ( 'Standard', [TLabeledPanel]);
end;

constructor TLabeledPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCaption := TLabeledPanelCaption.Create(Self);
  FCaption.Parent:= Self;
  with FCaption do begin
    Height:= 25;
    Width:= TLabeledPanel(Self).Width;
    Top:= 0;
    Left:= 0;
    Alignment:= taCenter;
    BorderStyle:= bsNone;
    Color:= clYellow;
    Caption:= TObject.UnitName;
  end;
  FTitle:= Caption;
end;

destructor TLabeledPanel.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
  //FreeAndNil(FCaption);
end;


procedure TLabeledPanel.SetCaption(const Value: String);
begin
  FTitle := Value;
  FCaption.Text:= FTitle;
end;

procedure TLabeledPanel.SetColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  FColor := Value;
  Color:=FColor;
  FCaption.Color:= FColor;
end;

procedure TLabeledPanel.SetShowCaption(const Value: boolean);
begin
  FShowCaption:= Value;
  case FShowCaption of
  True: FCaption.Visible:= True;
  False: FCaption.Visible:= False;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать несколько изменений  в коде что бы все работало в разных
ситуациях
Показал примерное направление в котором нужно двигатся когда создаете свои компоненты. Здесь важно понимать какие есть события у вашего контола и как с ними работать а написать все в одном конструкторе это не верный подход.
Даже если сразу ошибок не будет по потом начнутся, когда по другому начнет с компонентом взаимодействовать. Что бы понять что как работает рекомендую
поставить точку остановку на моменте создания контрола и проследить куда код заходит и какова очередность событий котрола. 1 раз день на это потратите потом сами себе спасибо скажите.

```
unit LabeledPanel;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Types,
  Math,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TLabeledPanel = class;
  //TLabeledPanelChange = procedure (Sender: TLabeledPanel; Title: String) of object;

  TLabeledPanelCaption = class(TRichEdit)

end;


  TLabeledPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FCaption: TLabeledPanelCaption;
    //FOnChange: TLabeledPanelChange;
    FTitle: String;
    FShowCaption: Boolean;
    FColor: TColor;
    procedure SetCaption(const Value: String);
    procedure SetShowCaption(const Value: boolean);
    procedure SetColor(const Value: TColor);
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published

    // зачем дублировать текст в двух местах в этом объекте и в TRichEdit
    // разве что когда  TRichEdit будет динамически менятся и нужно какбы заменять текст панели на TRichEdit
    // в остальных случаях  TRichEdit должен быть   Include(TRichEdit.FComponentStyle, csSubComponent)
    property Caption: String read FTitle write SetCaption;


    property ShowCaption: boolean read FShowCaption write SetShowCaption;

    // Color надо брать с TControl а не свой делать
    property Color: TColor read FColor write SetColor;

  end;


  // сделаем 2 класса панели один будет иметь возможность поменять ссылку на TRichEdit
  // 2й    TRichEdit будет вшит в  TPanel
  TCustomMemoClass = class of TCustomMemo;


  TPanelMemoLink = class (TPanel)
    private
      [weak]FMemo: TCustomMemo; // взял класс как можно ниже что бы разные мемо можно было установить
      FLockMemoChangeText:integer;
      FOnChangeCaption: TNotifyEvent;
      // когда в self происходят изменения font color text то нужно это синхронизировать с memo
      procedure CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
      procedure CMColorChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_COLORCHANGED;
      procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
      procedure MemoSet(const Value: TCustomMemo);
      procedure MemoNeedUpdate();
      procedure MemoNeedUpdateBounds;
    protected
      procedure CreateWnd;override;
      procedure Resize;override;
      procedure SetParent(W:TWinControl);override;
      procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
      procedure MemoUpdating;virtual;
      procedure MemoUpdatingBounds;virtual;
      procedure MemoSub;virtual;
      procedure MemoUnSub;virtual;
      procedure MemoChangeText(S:TObject);virtual;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
    published
      property Memo: TCustomMemo read FMemo write MemoSet;
      property OnChangeCaption: TNotifyEvent read FOnChangeCaption write FOnChangeCaption;
  end;

  TPanelMemo = class  (TPanelMemoLink)
    private
     FMemoSub:TCustomMemo;//добавил отдельное поле т.к в предке memo может менятся
     function MemoGet: TCustomMemo;
    protected
     procedure SetName(const AName:TComponentName);override;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      class function GetClassMemo:TCustomMemoClass;virtual;
    published
      property Memo: TCustomMemo read MemoGet;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation
 type
  TLocWinControl = class (TWinControl);
  TLocCustomEdit = class (TCustomEdit);

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents ( 'TestLabelPanel', [TPanelMemoLink,TPanelMemo]);
end;

constructor TLabeledPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCaption := TLabeledPanelCaption.Create(Self);
  // FCaption поле принято хранить текст а не объекты
  //   FCaption должен быть sub компонентом т.к  будет дублирования при хагрузке с ресурса формы
 // FCaption.Parent:= Self;   // парент должен назначатся в setParent  override
  with FCaption do begin
    Height:= 25;
    Width:= TLabeledPanel(Self).Width;
    Top:= 0;
    Left:= 0;
    Alignment:= taCenter;
    BorderStyle:= bsNone;
    Color:= clYellow;    // установка колола до установки парента может привести к ошибке получение хандела
    Caption:= TObject.UnitName;
  end;
  FTitle:= Caption;
end;

destructor TLabeledPanel.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
  //FreeAndNil(FCaption);
end;


procedure TLabeledPanel.SetCaption(const Value: String);
begin
  FTitle := Value;
  FCaption.Text:= FTitle;
end;

procedure TLabeledPanel.SetColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  FColor := Value;
  Color:=FColor;     // эта строка приведет к бесконечной рекурсии самый простой варик рещения это inherited Color:=FColor;
  FCaption.Color:= FColor;
end;

procedure TLabeledPanel.SetShowCaption(const Value: boolean);
begin
  //зачем так сложно если можно FShowCaption:= Value; FCaption.Visible:= FShowCaption;
  // но даже это не совсем верно
  FShowCaption:= Value;
  case FShowCaption of
  True: FCaption.Visible:= True;
  False: FCaption.Visible:= False;
  end;
end;

{ TPanelMemoLink }
constructor TPanelMemoLink.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FMemo:=nil;
  FLockMemoChangeText:=0;
  inherited;
  self.ParentColor:=false;
  self.ParentBackground:=false;
end;

destructor TPanelMemoLink.Destroy;
begin
  MemoUnSub;
  inherited;
  FMemo:=nil;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.CMColorChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    inherited;
    if Assigned(FMemo) and HandleAllocated and (Parent<>nil)  then
    TLocWinControl(FMemo).Color:= self.Color;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    inherited;
    if Assigned(FMemo) and HandleAllocated and (Parent<>nil)  then
    TLocWinControl(FMemo).Font:= self.Font;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
   inherited;
   if FLockMemoChangeText>0 then  exit;
   inc(FLockMemoChangeText);
   try
    if Assigned(FMemo) and HandleAllocated and (Parent<>nil)  then
    TLocWinControl(FMemo).Text:= self.Text;
    if Assigned(FOnChangeCaption) then
    FOnChangeCaption(self);
   finally
      dec(FLockMemoChangeText);
   end;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  MemoNeedUpdate;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoSet(const Value: TCustomMemo);
begin
   if FMemo <>  Value then
   begin
       if Assigned(FMemo) then
       MemoUnSub;
       FMemo:=nil;
       if Assigned(Value) then
       begin
         if  (csDestroying in Value.ComponentState) or (csDestroying in ComponentState) then exit;
         FMemo:= Value;
         if (FMemo.Parent<>nil) and (FMemo.Parent is TPanelMemoLink) then
         TPanelMemoLink(FMemo.Parent).Memo:=nil;
         MemoSub;
         MemoNeedUpdate;
       end;
   end;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoChangeText(S: TObject);
begin
   if FLockMemoChangeText>0 then  exit;
   inc(FLockMemoChangeText);
   try
       if FMemo<>nil then
       self.Caption:= FMemo.Text;
   finally
     dec(FLockMemoChangeText);
   end;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoNeedUpdate;
begin
  if Assigned(FMemo) and HandleAllocated and (Parent<>nil)  then
  MemoUpdating;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoUpdating;
begin
  if FMemo.Parent<>self then
  FMemo.Parent:= self;
  TLocWinControl(FMemo).Color:= self.Color;
  TLocWinControl(FMemo).Font:= self.Font;
  TLocWinControl(FMemo).Text:= self.Text;
  MemoUpdatingBounds;
end;
procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoNeedUpdateBounds;
begin
    if Assigned(FMemo) and HandleAllocated and (Parent<>nil)  then
    MemoUpdatingBounds;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoUpdatingBounds;
var R:TRect;
begin
   R:=  self.ClientRect;
   self.AdjustClientRect(R);
   FMemo.SetBounds(0,0,R.Width,min(50,R.Height));
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoSub;
begin
   FMemo.FreeNotification(self);
   FMemo.Visible:=true;
   TLocCustomEdit(FMemo).OnChange:= MemoChangeText;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.MemoUnSub;
begin
    FMemo.RemoveFreeNotification(self);
    if TMethod(TLocCustomEdit(FMemo).OnChange).Data = self then
    TLocCustomEdit(FMemo).OnChange:= nil;
    FMemo.Visible:=false;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if Operation = opRemove  then
  begin
    if AComponent = FMemo then
    FMemo:=nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  MemoNeedUpdateBounds;
end;

procedure TPanelMemoLink.SetParent(W: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(Parent) and  Assigned(FMemo) then
  MemoNeedUpdate;
end;

{ TPanelMemo }

constructor TPanelMemo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var M:TCustomMemo;
begin
  inherited;
  FMemoSub:=GetClassMemo.Create(self);
  FMemoSub.SetSubComponent(true);
  FMemoSub.Alignment:= taCenter;
  TLocCustomEdit(FMemoSub).BorderStyle:= bsNone;
  inherited  Memo := FMemoSub;
end;

destructor TPanelMemo.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

class function TPanelMemo.GetClassMemo: TCustomMemoClass;
begin
  Result:=  TRichEdit;
end;

function TPanelMemo.MemoGet: TCustomMemo;
begin
    Result:= inherited Memo;
end;

procedure TPanelMemo.SetName(const AName: TComponentName);
begin
  inherited;
  FMemoSub.Name:='MemoSub';
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Внутри SetColor строка

```
Color:=FColor;
```

Приводит к бесконечной рекурсии, т.к присвоение значения свойству Color снова вызывает SetColor и так далее.

Уберите эту строку.

Перенесите назначение свойств FCaption в

```
procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
```

Comment: Как работать с этой процедурой? Можно краткий гайд?

Comment: Создайте указанное объявление в интерфейсной части класса, реализуйте метод в implementation, перенесите туда  `with FCaption...` после inherited